# Extract comment property from result of exif_read_data()

Tags: php, exif

How do I return the *comment* property from exif_read_data

link:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

Comment: What exactly is your question - how to fetch it, or how address it in a result array? Is the manual's info about the `sections` parameter not sufficient?

Comment: @Pekka, I dont understand the parameters and yes get the image comment inside an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$comments = exif_read_data('tests/test2.jpg', 'COMMENT', true);

foreach ($comments as $name => $val) {
      echo "$name: $val<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: PHP must have changed a lot because if you actually want to get the comment, your code would have to look more like this:
`if($comments) echo $comments["COMMENT"][0];`